# Please change title of the highlighted blog post

Tags: bug, status-completed, title, blog, featured-tag

I take issue with the title of the [blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/06/18/adios-to-unfriendly-badges-ahoy-lifejacket-and-lifeboat/?cb=1) currently highlighted on so many SE pages.

The title says: "Adios to Unfriendly Badges: Ahoy, Lifejacket and Lifeboat" which leads one to believe that the unfriendly badges are "Ahoy," "Lifejacket," and "Lifeboat."  Veteran users might think it strange that these are unfriendly badges and don't recognize them as having even been introduced, because they hadn't previously been!

Also, the blog post mentions nothing about Ahoy, which is not a badge, but given the badge naming conventions, could be one issued for extending a hearty and friendly welcome, especially if trying to contrast "unfriendly."

At the least, I would use an exclamation point instead of a colon.  Better would be to also name the "unfriendly" badges being removed, as it's not clear to all that those are unfriendly (see other answers [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/386178/798371)).

For example: "Adios to Unfriendly Badges Tumbleweed and Reversal. Ahoy, Lifejacket and Lifeboat!"

Comment: They probably thought most people would know what [Ahoy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ahoy_(greeting)) means.

Comment: @AnneDaunted And they probably thought most people would know what "Lifejacket" and "Lifeboat" mean, but no, SE is giving a new meaning to those terms in its introduction of badges with those names.  There could just as easily be a badge named "Ahoy" and its introduction might have been misguided & unfriendly.  That is the more likely conclusion from the grammatical structure of the post title.

Comment: @AnneDaunted As the blog post is featured network-wide, it can be confusing to English language learners.

Comment: It just needs a semicolon instead of a colon.  (Or two sentences, which might be easier for non-native speakers.)

Comment: @MonicaCellio is that an Oxford semicolon?

Comment: @MonicaCellio Hence the recommendation to, at a minimum, use an exclamation point instead of a colon, probably adding one at the end too.  That would make it two punctuated sentences and easier to understand.

Comment: When I suggested this title, it was meant to be a title and a [subtitle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtitle_(titling)). For whatever reason, it just got left as a title. Hence the ambiguity. I looked into changing the title, but I'm apparently not able to edit published blog posts these days. I've left a note with the folks who have that ability and I expect they'll make a change next week. (I'm going on vacation next week, so I won't be around to make sure, however.)

Comment: @JonEricson I see this was done, nice!